# Is there a faster way to retrieve an array from a multi-dimensional array, using an array of indices?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to speed up a section of code that's called a LOT in the hope to cut a script run-time down.

Say I have a multidimensional array:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

And a single-dimensional array of indices:

```
[2], [0], [1]
```

Without a loop, is there a way to retrieve those indices from the multi-dimensional array, i.e,:

```
[3], [4], [8]
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: Does a list comprehension also count as for loop?

Comment: How big is your array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap)

```
import itertools


def get_values_from_indices(array_values, array_indices):
    """
    This function will accept two params, 
    once is a multi-dimensional list, and other one is list of indices.
    """
    return list(itertools.starmap(lambda x, y: x[y[0]], zip(array_values, array_indices)))
```

**DEMO**

```
multi_dimensional_array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
list_of_indices = [[2], [0], [1]]

result = get_values_from_indices(multi_dimensional_array , list_of_indices)

print(result)
# [3, 4, 8]
```

Comment: I'm already using itertools for flattening a multidimensional array - I'll give this a go and report back!

Comment: I've learned a lot about lambdas and iterables in the last hour and I've been able to do what I'd hoped using a map function.  Sadly, it's only slightly faster - but every bit counts!  Thanks heaps :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly how you would want your result, but with numpy you could achieve something similar below.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
# array([[1, 2, 3],
#   [4, 5, 6],
#   [7, 8, 9]])

a[[0,1,2],[2,0,1]] # array([3, 4, 8])
a[[0,1,2],[1,2,1]] # array([2, 6, 8])
```

May even be,

```
indices = [[2],[0],[1]]
a[range(len(indices)), np.reshape(indices, -1)] # array([3, 4, 8])
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions:

```
listOfList = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

indexInto = [2, 0, 1]       # first version works for this
indexTwo = [[2], [0], [1]]  # second version works for this

# first version
values = [listOfList[lili][indexInto[lili]] for lili in range(len(listOfList))] # both lists need same length

# second version
values2 = [listOfList[lili][indexTwo[lili][0]] for lili in range(len(listOfList))] # both lists need same length

print( values)
print( values2)
```

Output:

```
[3, 4, 8]    
[3, 4, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy solution:

```
import numpy as np

L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
ind = [[2], [0], [1]]
a = np.array(L)
b = np.array(ind)

c = a[np.arange(len(a)), b.reshape(-1)]
print (c.tolist())
[3, 4, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another numpy solution:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

a2 = [[2], [0], [1]]

a[np.arange(len(a)), np.concatenate(a2)]  # array([3, 4, 8])
```

Answer (score 0):

Lambda solution with map without importing any external module in just one line :

```
list_1=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
indices=[[2], [0], [1]]

print(list(map(lambda x,y :list(map(lambda z:x[z],y)),list_1,indices)))
```

output:

```
[[3], [4], [8]]
```